# Root of the Dependency Problem in Interval Arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic, interval-arithmetic

I have a question regarding the [dependency problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic#Dependency_problem) in interval arithmetics.

One common example that is often used to illustrate to problem is a function like

$f: [-1, 1] \rightarrow Y, \, f(x) = x \cdot x,$

with the task to compute $Y$ as accurate as possible. When applying interval arithmetic one gets $[-1, 1] \times[-1, 1] = [-1, 1]$ while the correct range is $[0, 1]$.

My question is now, can't this problem be solved by "recognizing" that the ranges depend on each other (just like a human would do it)? I mean from an implementation point of view, I could just asign each interval an extra flag which indicates on which variable it depends like:

$[-1, 1]_x \times [-1, 1]_y = \begin{cases} [-1, 1], &x \neq y\\ [0, 1], & x = y  \end{cases} \,,$

where the $x$ and $y$ subscripts denote on which variables the interval depends on.

I guess not all combinations could be resolved like this (especially if after some computation intervals depend on multiple variables), but the situation should get at least better, right? Is there some theoretical analysis on this available, especially when it would fail? I.e., what are the roots of the dependency problem?

And are there more sofisticated techniques available apart from dividing intervals in smaller subintervals or rewriting $f$ such that each variable appears exactly once (which is not always possible)?

Comment: I suspect it would be more manageable to have a special function for squaring. After all, your approach would have difficulties with $(x+y)^2$. - Note that the reult $[-1,1]$ is still correct in the sense that it guarantees that the true result is in that interval if the input values are in the repspectiv eintervals.

Comment: Hi, yes I know the result is correct in that it contains the true interval, but often the bounds are (way) too conservative to be useful. I don't think the method would have difficulties with the function $(x + y)^2$ since it would yield $[0, 4]$ as range, which is the correct range. Note that in your example there isn't even the need for such a detection because every variable occurs exactly once, so naiv interval arithmetic will be sufficient to calculate the exact range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the dependency problem in interval arithmetic *is* the multiple occurrence of one or more variables in an expression. When there are no multiple occurrences, the interval expression gives the exact result.

It is neither easy nor always possible to rewrite expressions by hand or even automatically to eliminate or reduce multiple occurrences.
The dependency problem needs automatic solutions [1]
such as centered forms, affine arithmetic, and Taylor models.

[1] Nedialkov et al, [Interval Arithmetic, Affine Arithmetic, Taylor Series Methods: Why, What Next?](https://doi.org/10.1023/B:NUMA.0000049478.42605.cf), *Numerical Algorithms* (2004)